# Point charge above infinite plate - with Legendre Polynomials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, potential, multipole-expansion

From the method of images we know that the potential everywhere above a grounded plate with a point charge above it is equal to

$$ V(x,y,z) = (\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0})[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + (z-d)^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + (z+d)^2}}] $$

$$  = (\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0})[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + d^2 - 2rd\cos(\theta)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + d^2 + 2rd\cos(\theta)}}] $$

$$  = (\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0})[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + d^2 - 2rd\cos(\theta)}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + d^2 - 2rd\cos(\theta')}}] $$

Where $\theta'$ is the angle between $r$ and the point $z = -d$.

To solve this problem with Laplaces equation and Legendre Polynomials we must express the problem in terms of a function $f$, with $\nabla^2f = 0$, and $V = V_0 + f$.

In this case, we know that $V$ must satisfy the condition that $V(r->\infty) = 0$, and that $V(\theta = \pi/2) = 0$. We know that, due to the free charge,

$$ V_0  = \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{r^2 + d^2 - 2rd\cos(\theta)}} $$

thus, the boudary conditions on $f$ are:

$$ f(r->\infty) = 0$$

$$ f(\theta = \pi/2) = \frac{-\lambda}{\sqrt{r^2 + d^2}} $$

Where $\lambda = (\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0})$.

These conditions are satisfied the multipole expansion of $\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{r^2 + d^2 - 2rd\cos(\theta)}}$:

$$ f(r, \theta) = (-\lambda)\sum_{l =0}^{\infty}\frac{r_<^l}{r_>^{l+1}}P_l(\cos\theta)$$

Where $r_<$ is less than $r_>$ are either $r$ or $d$.

However, we know that the solution to this problem is actually

$$ f(r, \theta) = (-\lambda)\sum_{l =0}^{\infty}\frac{r_<^l}{r_>^{l+1}}P_l(-\cos\theta) = (-\lambda)\sum_{l =0}^{\infty}(-1)^l\frac{r_<^l}{r_>^{l+1}}P_l(\cos\theta)$$

How do we derive the real answer from the boundary conditions?

Answer (score 2):

You have the correct setup with the image charge, you just aren't doing the expansion correctly. For starters, with a grounded plate the definition of "grounded" is that the potential of the plate is 0, so:
$$\Phi\left(\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0.$$
If the plate were at some other constant potential (and it must be constant since it's a conducting plate), that would be given in the problem and can be added to the grounded plate solution.

Next, we can get the needed expansions from your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/329893/multipole-expansion-relative-to-point-z-d), and apply it to the potential from the [method of image charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges):
$$\begin{align}
\Phi(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}') &= \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left[\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|} - \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r} - \Pi_z \mathbf{r}'|}\right]\ \\
&\qquad (\Pi_z\ \mathrm{is\ the\ parity\ operator\ that\ reflects\ across\ the\ }z=0\mathrm{\ plane}) \\
& = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + d^2 - 2dr\cos\theta}}- \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2 + d^2 - 2dr\cos(\pi - \theta)}}\right] \\
& = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left[ \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{r_<^\ell}{r_>^{\ell+1}}P_\ell(\cos \theta) - \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty \frac{r_<^\ell}{r_>^{\ell+1}}P_\ell(-\cos \theta)\right] \\
& = \frac{2q}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \left[ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{r_<^{2n+1}}{r_>^{2n+2}}P_{2n+1}(\cos \theta)\right].
\end{align}$$
That is, the potential is a sum over the odd Legendre polynomials because they are the ones that possess the correct parity (negative) under reflection across the $z=0$ plane.

Comment: This works in this case, because we already know the position of the charge required to set the potential to be 0 across the conducting plate. However, in the event that we have no knowledge about where this charge should be (i.e., in the case that the configuration is actually of an infinite plate with a bump pointing away from the charge), we would not be able to do this. 

In other words, i'm attempting to find that there should be a charge at that position without just guessing and checking.

Comment: Are you talking about a deformation of the plate [ "(i.e., in the case that the configuration is actually of an infinite plate with a bump pointing away from the charge)"], or a continuous charge distribution above the plate?

Comment: Deformation of the plate. But that is different problem than the one I am asking about here. It is just that the problem of the deformed plate is only solvable in the method of finding an $f$ where $\nabla^2f = 0$ and $V = V_{due-to-charges} + f$ at all boundary conditions

Comment: So, the potential due to charges is found using the method of images with $\Phi=0$ on the boundary, as we're doing here. That's what describes the way you can add a charge without disturbing the value of $\Phi$ on the boundary. This potential is the Green's function discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Green.27s_functions_for_the_Laplacian) (and in Jackson) that is appropriate for [Dirichlet boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_boundary_condition).

Comment: For some systems, like the problem of an infinite conductor with a circle cut out of it and a hemisphere of equal radius "welded" on the circle, the method of images is insufficient for deriving a problem.

Comment: Finding the $\Phi(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}')$ for a point charge at $\mathbf{r'}$ that satisfies $\Phi=0$ for $\mathbf{r}$ on the boundary isn't always straightforward, but doing so is sufficient to solve the problem regardless of boundary shape. When the boundary really gets complicated, you don't turn to multipole expansions but to numerical (like [relaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_(iterative_method))) or perturbative methods (described later in Jackson).